# ERROR com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados

Tags: sql, java-8

Realizo la extracción de información para guardar a en un Array, sin embargo me bota el siguiente error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:444)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:297)
```

el codigo para extraer la información es el siguiente:

```
try {
            Connection con = null;
            con = getConection();
            PreparedStatement pSs;
            ResultSet resS;
            pSs = con.prepareStatement("EXEC PROCEDIMIENTO '" + COMBO1.getSelectedItem() + "','" + COMBO2.getSelectedItem() + "' ");           
            resS = pSs.executeQuery();
            info.clear();
            while (resS.next()) {
                String[] resu = new String[4];
                resu[0] = resS.getString(1).trim();
                resu[1] = resS.getString(2).trim();
                resu[2] = resS.getString(3).trim();
                resu[3] = resS.getString(4).trim();


                info.add(resu);
            }

            int arregloTam = info.size();
            String[][] data = new String[arregloTam][4];
            for (int i = 0; i < arregloTam; i++) {
                data[i] = (String[]) info.get(i);

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BimAnexos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Ya revise mi conexión con otra consulta y todo esta perfecto, solo en especifico con esta consulta me arroja el error.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del contenido que envías en  `con.prepareStatement("EXEC PROCEDIMIENTO '" + COMBO1.getSelectedItem() + "','" + COMBO2.getSelectedItem() + "' ");`?

Comment: Es una ejecución de este estilo `EXEC PA_BIMESTRALES  'BIM6' , '1' `

Comment: Y estás seguro que tu procedimiento regresa algo?

Comment: Si no regresa valor, ya detecte el problema es una tabla temporal la que me esta dando problema, gracias!!